# Com Visibility in referenced assemblies

Tags: .net, com, comvisible

If I have the follwing assemblies:

MyComVisibleApi:  a .Net assembly that is used by a VB app

MyReferencedAssembly:  a .Net assembly referenced by MyComVisibleApi

Does MyReferencedAssembly need to be ComVisible if its functionality is never directly referenced by the VB App?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have to make `MyReferencedAssembly` `ComVisible` unless you use types from `MyReferencedAssembly` in the public signatures of `MyComVisibleApi`.  Public signatures include properties, method parameters and return types.

There is also a special case: if you derive a `ComVisible` type from a type that is not `ComVisible`, public base class members will be exposed to COM as members of the derived class unless those members are individually `[ComVisible(false)]`.